# How can I return zero from this Double.parseDouble call if the string I'm parsing is empty?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener //Action from listner

        {public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent c)

              {double total = 0;
               double hours = Double.parseDouble(thours.getText());
               double pcharge = Double.parseDouble(tparts.getText());
               if(coil.isSelected()){total += 26;}
               if(clube.isSelected()){total += 18;}
               if(cradiator.isSelected()){total += 30;}
               if(ctransmission.isSelected()){total += 80;}
               if(cinspection.isSelected()){total += 15;}
               if(cmuffler.isSelected()){total += 100;}
               if(ctire.isSelected()){total += 20;}
               else{total = total;}
               total += (pcharge + (hours*20));
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total Charges : $" + total);}}
```

"thours" and "tparts" are the fields that are a user imput for a number, but since I am doing calculations with this value, I believe it's returning an error because this line has no value. How can I cause this code to return zero in this case?

Comment: Please define which programming language(c#,java,javascript...or any other). And please provide more code and elaborate your problem

Comment: What do you mean `return 0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean set the variable value to `0`. If not, please clarify.

Use a ternary expression to do this. For example for `hours`, use:

```
double hours = thours.getText().isEmpty() ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(thours.getText());
```

If `thours.getText().isEmpty()` is true, `hours` will be set to `0`. Otherwise, `hours` will be set to `Double.parseDouble(thours.getText())`.

Answer (score 0):

```
double hours;
if (!"".equals(thours.getText()))}{
    try {
        hours = Double.parseDouble(thours.getText());
    } catch (NUmberFormatException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDilaog(null, "Please enter a valid number");
    }
}
```

Code checks if text has any characters, than a try/catch to catch any number format exception if the input is a not a number